# DSLR filmmaking tutorials and tips

Tags: video, dslr

The title says it all. I have a DSLR and would like to learn more about video, from basics to advanced (I am an intermediate+ photographer). Are there good tutorials I can find online? I could not find much but very basic intros on the web.

Comment: This one may be tough to answer in its current form.  Presently, it's wide open... no constraints whatsoever.  To, "learn more about video, from basics to advanced," covers everything, yet points to nothing.  Do you have a first project in mind?  Have you come across troubles so far?  Please edit to narrow your question's scope.

Comment: Actually this could be a very good question if it included the *specifics* of using DSLR camera when filming. For example, how to work with lenses properly? Since these were not destined for filming, there is no auto-focus. So one of the aspects could be How to handle the DSLRs manual focus when filming..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best suggestion I can come up with is to get a book on cinematography.  There isn't really much in the way of difference between using a DSLR for video versus any other camera.  The techniques are all the same, just the mechanics of the particular camera differ.

The best way to learn the mechanics of a camera is just to read the manual and try it.  The way to figure out what you need to use those mechanics to do is to study cinematography in general.

Beyond that, if you have more specific questions, I'm sure we can help you with those in more detail.